# Spring-batch, ItemReadListener [SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed]

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch, sybase, connection-pooling

My application is about parsing and processing a huge file and that by invoking dao methods to check existing of some attributs in a sybase database.
We have used for that spring batch and multi-threading mechanism and so that we have occured an exception in afterRead method of the class ItemReadListener caused by an SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed."

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select count(*) from USER_SERVICE where user_serv_oidval = ?]; SQL state [HY010]; error code [0]; Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:805)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:824)
at com.orange.essentials.dao.impl.ServiceDaoImpl.isExistServiceById(ServiceDaoImpl.java:28)
at com.orange.essentials.services.ItemReadListenerFunctionalValidator.afterRead(ItemReadListenerFunctionalValidator.java:51)
at com.orange.essentials.services.ItemReadListenerFunctionalValidator.afterRead(ItemReadListenerFunctionalValidator.java:1)
at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeItemReadListener.afterRead(CompositeItemReadListener.java:60)
at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.MulticasterBatchListener.afterRead(MulticasterBatchListener.java:232)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:93)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.checkOpen(ConnectionJDBC2.java:1714)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2435)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1557)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:638)

Comment: Have you tried to run it single threaded to figure out wether it is a threading issue? It looks like the connection was either not opened or was closed already. Have you tried to figure out which object and thread called the close method on the connection?

Comment: Yes i have tried to run it single threaded but the same problem.

Comment: ok, in this case I would debug it single threaded. Inside ConnectionJDBC2, closed is initialised with false, meaning that the connection is open. Make a breakpoint at the beginning of the close() method and in the setClosed() method. These are the only places, when the internal "closed" member is set to true. This could help to understand, why the connection is closed.